# Where can I find SLAs for AWS CloudFormation APIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Looking for SLA of CloudFormation APIs like [listExports](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/cloudformation/CloudFormationClient.html#listExports--).

Is there any doc like [this](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/sla/) for CloudFormation?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a service level agreement for CloudFormation [in the list of SLAs](https://aws.amazon.com/legal/service-level-agreements/)

Comment: I suspect the argument would be that production services shouldn't rely on CloudFormation - a temporary glitch in being able to deploy / reference stacks shouldn't cause an issue.